# Is it possible to call 2 services that return 2 different type of lists in 1 service?

Tags: java, list, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to get data from 2 different tables, A and B, and I create the whole structure of Entity, Dto object and stuff. Then I was wondering, because I created two services, one that returns a `List<A>` list Object, and another that returns a `List<B>` object. I want the controller to return me both lists in 1 request, can I make a service that autowires both and returns me a `List<C>` object that contains both? So I can use it in the controller that has the request I want.
I searched online and I found 2 services in 1 controller, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Do you mean possibility of injecting services A and B into service C? Yes, you can do it.

Comment: Have you tried.. Because it should work

Comment: please show us your approach so that we can extend/modify it to help you out. Everybody here is to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a C service that injectes A and B services, with a method that creates a C object and populates it with the result of A and B services calls.

Depending your neededs you can create a C object that have two properties, one of List type and other with List type, and simply return it, or in case it has sense you can create an C object with an A property and a B property and return a List.

If you bring us an example maybe we can help you better.